# Authentication error when connecting to Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, node.js, authentication, node-postgres

I'm developing a Node.js application using PostgreSQL and hosting on Heroku. My problem is that I get an authentication error like so:

```
14:32:05 web.1     | { [error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "193.40.244.196", user "username", database "database_name", SSL off]
14:32:05 web.1     |   length: 168,
14:32:05 web.1     |   name: 'error',
14:32:05 web.1     |   severity: 'FATAL',
14:32:05 web.1     |   code: '28000',
14:32:05 web.1     |   detail: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   hint: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   position: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   internalPosition: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   internalQuery: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   where: undefined,
14:32:05 web.1     |   file: 'auth.c',
14:32:05 web.1     |   line: '483',
14:32:05 web.1     |   routine: 'ClientAuthentication' }
```

It might be an SSL problem, but it shouldn't be as mentioned [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/25). SSL should be supported out of the box. So I'm stumped and can only ask what might cause this error?

I'm not sure if I have to maybe edit the pg_hba.conf on my system, but I can't even find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into this myself, it's a simple fix. Just connect over HTTPS instead

Comment: Usually just forcing the port to 5572 of the one listed with `heroku config` would suffice.

Comment: "Just connect over HTTPS instead".  Could you elaborate?  Do you mean specify port 5572 as David Pelaez suggests?  That doesn't work for me, nor does specifying ssl: true in the params as someone else suggested, nor does specifying both.  I'm using the javascript bindings, not native.

Answer (score 48):

Solved it by setting `PGSSLMODE` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-envars.html) on Heroku. It tells PostgreSQL to default to SSL.

```
$ heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require
```

Comment: Agreed. This is the best answer as it kept my local and remote versions working with the least amount of code.

Comment: It's indeed the most exact answer, as other solutions provided don't make use of process.env.DATABASE_URL

Comment: Excellent! After hours, this was my solution. Thank you.

Comment: Ran into this problem when I upgraded my postgresql instance https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-pg-upgrade.  PGSSLMODE was the fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should be the answer.

Comment: This is a [good discussion](https://ankane.org/postgres-sslmode-explained) of the meanings of the settings available for PGSSLMODE, in case anyone else finds it helpful.

Comment: @Carlos.V happy to help! :D

Comment: For my use case, I had to set PGSSLMODE to no-verify as per Heroku's docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

Answer (score 27):

node-postgres doesn't support SSL in it's javascript bindings, which you're using if you do:

```
var pg = require('pg');
```

To get SSL, you need to use the native binding by doing this:

```
var pg = require('pg').native;
```

You **don't** need to use SSL when your app is running inside Heroku, you only need to use SSL to connect remotely (when your app is running locally).

Comment: One does not need native binding to run SSL anymore.

Comment: Worked for me...thanks! (if you are using Sequelize, add `native: true` to the `new Sequelize` options object)

Comment: This requires `npm i pg-native`

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js says to set `pg.defaults.ssl = true;` before connecting.

Answer (score 19):

I added these params and can now connect to my heroku postgres instance from an outside server, specifically, in configuration of knex.js in a node express server:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: 'postgres://username:password@host:5432/yourdbname?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory'
});
```

Comment: thanks for the knex example! Where did you find this information?

Comment: not sure! but I see it's documented, so perhaps it was here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java

Comment: This also helped me with local nodejs development using heroku postgre db

Answer (score 9):

Ran into same issue. Just Enabled ssl=true in the db params.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var params = { host: 'heroku_hostname',user: 'username',password: 'password',database: 'database',ssl: true };
var client = new pg.Client(params);
client.connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

I too received the `'ClientAuthentication'` `no pg_hba.conf entry` error in my Heroku PRODUCTION instance in April 2021.  I was and continue to use the Plan "Hobby Dev" free account.

Heroku began rolling out changes to the platform in February 2021 that enforced SSL for all Heroku Postgres client connections.  [All Heroku Postgres client connections require SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2035).

I fixed my PRODUCTION instance (where my NextJS App connected to the Heroku Postgres add-on) by adding the following config `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` when using [node-postgres v8](https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl):

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Here's what helped me.

```
new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = new Pool({
   connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
   ...
   ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});
```

I just resolved the issue by adding the `ssl: { rejectUnautorized: false }` to my database configuration. Also, run `heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify -a appName`

NOTE: "appName" should be the name of your hosted application